# I am not getting reply button for comments. I get only copytext, share and the user buttons. I have a 290 reputation

Tags: bug, android-app

- App Version: 1.0.93
- Device Manufacturer: asus
- Device Model: Nexus 7

  - OS Version: 7.1.2 (4a5f30b4fd)

Comment: Old bug (one of many) that never got fixed, and most likely will never be fixed.